# Threading text like in Indesign with HTML/JS

Tags: javascript, html, text, adobe-indesign

How to program threading text like in frames in Indesign.
Link: http://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/threading-text.html

I want to use three columns in HTML. In these columns I will add one text. Whenever the content of the text exceed the column height, the text should pass over to the next column. The last column don't pass the text content.

Comment: At least IE10 has this: [Multi-column layout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673534%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). And at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_multi-column_layouts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use column-count css property, with browser specific prefixes for Firefox and Chrome.

Beware, it doesn't work in IE <10

```
-moz-column-count:3;
-webkit-column-count:3;
column-count:3;
```